# Use Google wallet with braintree payment gateway

Tags: android-pay, braintree

I want to know, can i use google wallet with braintree payment gateway in android application. To be more technical clear, take MASKEDWallet from google wallet and fetch all useful information from it and send it to braintree payment gateway for completing the purchase.

Please help.

Comment: I work at Braintree. The answer below looks correct for the Google Wallet side of the problem. If you have trouble with the Braintree side once you've fetched the full wallet from Google, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: agf, from full wallet i get proxy card then how can i send proxy card to braintree gateway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a couple of days into working on same, so this is devoid of technical specifics (more conceptual). Also I'm doing so on the "web" side of `Wallet Instant Buy` (not Android), though the concept of sending payment details through, and meeting (PCI) requirements, to your (any) credit card payment gateway should be the same.

Unless I'm corrected by a Googler:

You'll need to make a [`FullWalletRequest`](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/android/tutorial#request_the_full_wallet) to obtain the "full wallet" which means the actual card details that you need to send to your gateway (card no, cvc/cvv, expiration, billing address etc.).

At which point, it wouldn't differ from any other/existing (gateway type) credit card processing.

At the end of the day, what Google Wallet Instant Buy does:

- provide a merchant application (droid/ios/web) a ["Virtual Onetime Card"](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/payment-flows#the_virtual_onetime_card), which,
- represents a Google Wallet user's *real card* stored in his/her Google Wallet account, therefore securing actual card details and scoping the transaction (because it's one-time)

I would think the only possible caveat is whether or not a gateway accepts such type of of card (*" a MasterCard-branded virtual prepaid debit card"*)..unlikely that would be an issue (in US, which is where the API is limited to at this time...)....

Digressing a bit. The other caveat that comes to mind is if you employ some fraud screening service. You're given a "virtual card" (not the real card of a cardholder), so if your service uses/needs that information to come up with a *risk score*, then its something you need to account for...

Hth....

Comment: Edsf, you mean to say that I can use virtual card information for payment through braintree. But I tried and it says that "Could not authorised your credit card". I checked on SANDBOX Environment.PLease help.

Comment: @PralabhJain I'll _assume_ that's a response from _Braintree_ ? If so, it's best to contact them directly for support. They do have sandbox. My **guess** would be that it's because their (Braintree) sandbox **only** expects/accepts [test card numbers](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/java/reference/sandbox)

Comment: @EdSF is correct. Its because the card number returned by instant buy in sandbox is not one of the test card numbers the process fails. In essence you have it working. You should apply for production accesss to Instant buy